# My flask app is fetching data from third party API , while deploying this app on EC2 , its getting hanged

Tags: api, flask, amazon-ec2

app.py is running fine , on ubuntu EC2 virtual machine .

[image: Screenshot]

But , when I run it with EC2 DCN , its keep on loading , doesn't show any output.

```
flask import jsonify, Flask
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__,template_folder='template')

@app.route('/')
def index():
    page = requests.get('https://www.nseindia.com/api/option-chain-indices?symbol=NIFTY' , headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
    page=json.loads(page.text)
    ce_values = [data['CE'] for data in page['records']['data'] if "CE" in data and data['expiryDate'] == "11-Feb-2021"]
    ce_dt = pd.DataFrame(ce_values).sort_values(['strikePrice'])
    return render_template('simple_VPS.html',  tables=[ce_dt.to_html(classes='data', header="true")])
```

Any solutions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`nseindia` is **blocking** requests originating from AWS and other main cloud providers. It is an issue know for a [few](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/forums/topic/12471/) years now.

You can check with `nseindia` if they offer some subscription plans which would allow you to whitelist your IPs from AWS. Otherwise, don't use AWS to access them.

Comment: is there any other cloud platform which I can use ?

Comment: @KunalDeore I'm not aware of any. Its try and see approach to check. You could try a commercial VPN, but then you have to consider ethical/legal consequences of bypassing these blocks.